# How to pass more than one parameter to map function in panda

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a following dataFrame

```
mn = pd.DataFrame({'fld1': [2.23, 4.45, 7.87, 9.02, 8.85, 3.32, 5.55],'fld2': [125000, 350000,700000, 800000, 200000, 600000, 500000],'lType': ['typ1','typ2','typ3','typ1','typ3','typ1','typ2'], 'counter': [100,200,300,400,500,600,700]})
```

Mapping function

```
def getTag(rangeAttribute):
    sliceDef = {'tag1': [1, 4], 'tag2': [4, 6], 'tag3': [6, 9],
                'tag4': [9, 99]}
    for sl in sliceDef.keys():
        bounds = sliceDef[sl]
        if ((float(rangeAttribute) >= float(bounds[0]))
            and (float(rangeAttribute) <= float(bounds[1]))):
            return sl


def getTag1(rangeAttribute):
    sliceDef = {'100-150': [100000, 150000],
                '150-650': [150000, 650000],
                '650-5M': [650000, 5000000]}
    for sl in sliceDef.keys():
        bounds = sliceDef[sl]
        if ((float(rangeAttribute) >= float(bounds[0]))
            and (float(rangeAttribute) <= float(bounds[1]))):
            return sl
```

I want to compute sum based on the tags for fld1 and fld2.
At present I have to write different functions with hardcoded values for different types of field. MAP function only takes 1 argument. Is there any other function other than  MAP
that can also take sliceDef as input param.

```
mn.groupby([mn['fld1'].map(getTag),mn['fld2'].map(getTag1),'lType'] ).sum()
```

Comment: I don't think so map operates on each element in a series, if you want to pass do something with multiple arguments on a row-wise basis then you could use `apply` and set `axis=1` like so `mn.apply(lambda row: getTag(row), axis=1)` in `getTag` you can select the columns like so: `row['fld1']` and `row['fld2']`. This should achieve what you want

Comment: You might also be interested in looking at `pd.cut`, e.g. `pd.cut(mn.fld1, [1, 4, 6, 9, 99], right=False)`.  It's not quite in the same form as what you're looking for, but it's pretty convenient in my experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using map, you could use [pd.cut](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) (Thanks to DSM and Jeff for pointing this out):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mn = pd.DataFrame(
    {'fld1': [2.23, 4.45, 7.87, 9.02, 8.85, 3.32, 5.55],
     'fld2': [125000, 350000, 700000, 800000, 200000, 600000, 500000],
     'lType': ['typ1', 'typ2', 'typ3', 'typ1', 'typ3', 'typ1', 'typ2'],
     'counter': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700]})

result = mn.groupby(
    [pd.cut(mn['fld1'], [1,4,6,9,99], labels=['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4']),
     pd.cut(mn['fld2'], [100000, 150000, 650000, 5000000],
            labels=['100-150', '150-650', '650-5M']),
     'lType']).sum()

print(result)
```

yields

```
                    counter   fld1    fld2
             lType                        
tag1 100-150 typ1       100   2.23  125000
     150-650 typ1       600   3.32  600000
tag2 150-650 typ2       900  10.00  850000
tag3 150-650 typ3       500   8.85  200000
     650-5M  typ3       300   7.87  700000
tag4 650-5M  typ1       400   9.02  800000
```

This will be quicker than calling `getTag` or `getTag1` *once for every value in series*. Instead, `pd.cut` uses [np.searchsorted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) which returns *all* the indices with just one call (and moreover, `searchsorted` uses O(log n) binary search written in C instead of an O(n) loop written in Python).

---

**A subtle point:** The keys returned by `sliceDef.keys()` are not guaranteed to be in any particular order. It could change even from run to run (at least with Python3). Your criterion uses fully closed intervals:

```
    if ((float(rangeAttribute) >= float(bounds[0]))
        and (float(rangeAttribute) <= float(bounds[1]))):
```

so it might matter which key is tested first if `rangeAttribute` happens to fall on one of the values in `bounds`.

So your current code is non-deterministic.

`pd.cut` uses half-open intervals, so each value will fall into one and only one category, thus avoiding the problem.

---

**And to answer the general question:** Yes, there is a way to pass extra arguments -- use apply instead of map (Thanks to Andy Hayden for pointing this out):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def getTag(rangeAttribute, sliceDef):
    for sl in sliceDef.keys():
        bounds = sliceDef[sl]
        if ((float(rangeAttribute) >= float(bounds[0]))
            and (float(rangeAttribute) <= float(bounds[1]))):
            return sl

sliceDef = {'tag1': [1, 4], 'tag2': [4, 6], 'tag3': [6, 9],
            'tag4': [9, 99]}
sliceDef1 = {'100-150': [100000, 150000],
            '150-650': [150000, 650000],
            '650-5M': [650000, 5000000]}

mn = pd.DataFrame(
    {'fld1': [2.23, 4.45, 7.87, 9.02, 8.85, 3.32, 5.55],
     'fld2': [125000, 350000, 700000, 800000, 200000, 600000, 500000],
     'lType': ['typ1', 'typ2', 'typ3', 'typ1', 'typ3', 'typ1', 'typ2'],
     'counter': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700]})

result = mn.groupby([mn['fld1'].apply(getTag, args=(sliceDef, ))
                     ,mn['fld2'].apply(getTag, args=(sliceDef1, )),
                     'lType'] ).sum()
print(result)
```

Still, I don't recommend using `apply` for this particular problem since `pd.cut` is be faster, easier to use, and avoids the non-deterministic order of dict keys problem. But knowing that `apply` can take additional positional arguments may help you in the future.

---

Comment: looking back at this, I think rather than use partial you can use `.apply(getTag, sliceDef)`

Comment: @AndyHayden: Wow, I didn't know you could do that! Thanks.

Comment: I think this is basically what pd.cut does (and then you can groupby on the returned intervals).

Comment: @Jeff and @DSM: Thanks. I've changed the answer to use `pd.cut` instead of `np.searchsorted`.